# Wordpress tinyMCE error "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' tinymce.min.js:1"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to set up a Wordpress page for one of our customers but for some reasons i keep getting this error (see headline)

I tried installing a raw Wordpress on other Servers. always the same Result

Full console log:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
>   "/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js?ver=4107-20150118".
>       post.php?post=2&action=edit:1875 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
>   "/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js?ver=4107-20150118".
>       7post.php?post=2&action=edit:1 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does
>   not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query
>   expression: print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
>   (min-resolution: 120dpi)
>       post.php?post=2&action=edit:243 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does
>   not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query
>   expression: print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
>   (min-resolution: 120dpi)
>       tinymce.min.js?ver=4107-20150118:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>       plugin.min.js?ver=4107-20150118:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
>       post.php?post=2&action=edit:1877 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
>       3load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery…:896
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

I've never seen this happen in any Wordpress version before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix it on my own now so this answer is just for people experiencing the same problem:

So apparently the issue appeared because the folder itself, where the wordpress page was set up in was .. inside some more folders that apparently caused problems. I moved the folder into the very parent folder and now everything is working perfectly.